# Does the diffeomorphism group preserving a particular section act transitively?

Tags: differential-topology, complex-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, gr.group-theory

Let $\mathcal{D} \approx \mathbb{P}^{\delta_d}$, be the space of homogeneous 
degree $d$ polynomials in three  variables $[X,Y,Z] \in \mathbb{P}^2$ upto scaling, where 
$\delta_d = \frac{d(d+3)}{2}$. Note that we have two tautological line bundles 
$$ \gamma_{\mathcal{D}} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}, \qquad \gamma_{\mathbb{P}^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2.$$
Note that we have a natural section of the line bundle
$$ \psi: \mathcal{D} \times \mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow 
  \gamma_{\mathcal{D}}^* \otimes \gamma_{\mathbb{P}^2}^{*d}  $$
given by 
$$ \psi( [s], p) = s(p) $$ 
Let 
$$ g : \mathcal{D} \times \mathbb{P}^2 \rightarrow \mathcal{D} \times \mathbb{P}^2$$
be a diffeomorphism (need not be a biholomorphism).

Consider the subgroup under 
which $\psi$ is invariant, i.e. 
$$ \psi \circ g = \psi. $$
Does this subgroup act transitively on $\mathcal{D} \times \mathbb{P}^2$ ? 
In other words given any two points $([s_1], p_1)$ and $([s_2], [p_2])$ does 
there always exist a diffeomorphism preserving $\psi$ that takes one point to 
the other? 
More generally consider the section 
$$ \psi_2: \mathcal{D} \times ((\mathbb{P}^2)^2 - \Delta)\rightarrow 
  \gamma_{\mathcal{D}}^* \otimes \gamma_{\mathbb{P}^2}^{*d} \oplus 
 \gamma_{\mathcal{D}}^* \otimes \gamma_{\mathbb{P}^2}^{*d}  $$
given by 
$$ \psi_2 ([s], p_1, p_2) = s(p_1), s(p_2).$$ 
Does the subgroup of 
$$\mathcal{Diff} ( \mathcal{D} \times ((\mathbb{P}^2)^2 - \Delta))$$
under which $\psi_2$ is invariant act transitively on 
$\mathcal{D} \times ((\mathbb{P}^2)^2 - \Delta)$? Here 
$\Delta$ is the diagonal. 
Finally I have the same question for $k$ distinct 
points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the meaning of the equation $\psi\circ g=\psi$ as I don't see how to compare a section at two different points without fixing an isomorphism between the line-bundle and its pull-back under $g$. Anyway, in any possible interpretation, I don't think the group preserving $\psi$ acts transitively as it should preserve  the zero locus of $\psi$.

Comment: You are right, my question makes no sense. I guess I meant to 
say that the section is $G$ equivariant in some sense, but for 
that there has to be an action of the group on the Vector bundle
as well. Very naively what I was thinking is the following......
consider this section 
s([X,Y]) = X^2 + Y^2. Is there any sense in which I can say 
the section is ``invariant'' under the action of Z2 (i.e. [X,Y] going 
to [Y,X])?  